# ZF2 Get value of both POST and GET

Tags: zend-framework2

In ZF1, I could do following to get both $_POST and $_GET value.

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('foo');
```

Is there any method similar to this in ZF2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box you can't you have to check both separately:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('foo'); // $_POST
$this->getRequest()->getQuery('foo'); // $_GET
```

Comment: it doesn't take much to write a method to check both, but it's probably better to know exactly where you're getting the data from for security, which is probably why it's gone.

Comment: A few less chars but ultimately the same: the `params()` plugin: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-params-plugin